# Creating a hash table and nodes from a paragraph of words

Tags: c, hashtable

I have a paragraph of words, and I want to chuck each word into a hash table, and divide them evenly amongst the buckets.

My issue is, I have the hash table, and I've got the code written for the nodes, as they seem the easiest, however what do I do to have the code read the paragraph of text, and then spit each word into the hash table? I'm using the a while loop, with fscanf but I'm stuck on what to write after

```
while (fscanf(paragraph, "%s", paragraph_word) != EOF)
{
```

If it helps, my hash table and nodes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < HASHTABLE_SIZE; i++)
{
    hashtable[i] = NULL;
}

if (new_node == NULL)
{
    unload();
    return false;
}
```

This is my hash function, that I obtained online.

```
int hash_it(char* word)
{
unsigned int hash = 0;
for (int i=0, n=strlen(word); i<n; i++)
    hash = (hash << 2) ^ word[i];
return hash % hashtable_size;
}
```

**Question**: How do I use fscanf to read each word in a paragraph and then place them into a hash table, with even buckets?

Comment: I'm confused about the question.  Once you have the words, you feed each word to the hash function to generate the hash-table bucket index.  You then store the word at that bucket in the hash table.  If your hash function is good, this will result in an approximately-uniform distribution of the words over the hash-table buckets.  If your hash is too large to be a table index, take it modulo the number of table indices (which, if that's a power of 2, won't harm your uniformity)

Comment: Hi lockcmp! Thank you for the reply. I guess my main question is how exactly do I go from what I have (therefore just the above code), to actually feeding the words into the hash function? I guess I'm having trouble linking all these different concepts into creating the end product.

Answer (score 0):

We use hashtable to store a pair of things, the examples often given is you store a name, and with that you want to retrieve his adresses or phone number ...
but here (maybe I have misendurstood something but ?) you want to store a word into an hashtable, but you are using as index the word to retrieve the word.
with my example you obtain something like that :

```
int index = hash_it(some_random_name)
hashtable[index];//this will give you his phone number for example;
```

but with your problem

```
int index = hash_it(some_word_in_paragraph);
hashtable[index];//this will give you the word, but you had it already at 
// the time you were passing it to the function hash_it
```

so if I've well understood the question, i think a changing of data structure you're having might be good;